# Chlorination of 2-phenylbutane

Tags: organic-chemistry, hydrocarbons, halogenation

[image]

When the compound is chlorinated on the extreme carbons, there is a chiral carbon in both the resulting compounds, which gives a total of 4 stereo isomers. When compound is chlorinated on 2nd or 3rd carbon, it still has a chiral carbon in both resulting compounds. So the total stereo isomers add up to 8 according to me, but it doesn't match the options given.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, welcome to ChemSE! I presume that you are a student, which I am not, and that this problem arises from a preparatory examination. Too many of these types of questions are ambiguous at best and this one is no exception. The *sec*-butylbenzene as drawn in question 33 must be assumed to be racemic because there is no indication that it is a single enantiomer. The products are presumed to be monochlorinated and that the fractionating column is achiral and infinite in plates. In the diagram below, the Products (P) are presumed to be constitutional and stereoisomeric while the Fractions are designated as (F).

For the racemate, five Products are formed along with their respective enantiomers. Thus, P=10 and F=5, which is not an option in the answers. Even if the secondary chlorides were deemed inseparable, then the values would only be P=8, F=4 and also not an option. If the reactant were a single enantiomer, either *R* or *S*, then the total number of Products is six (P=6) and Fractions five (F=5). In this instance, answer (a) would be correct.

BTW: It is advisable not to accept answers too quickly thereby giving others an opportunity to respond. Who knows? There may be an answer you like better.

[image]

Comment: I am confused by the config change in the benzyl carbon should it not remain R except for benzyl chlorination.  Also liking should have little to do with it. Your much more accurate answer is what should be of importance.

Comment: @jimchmst: Introduction of chlorine at the methylene carbon changes the priorities of the atoms attached to the benzylic carbon. The configuration at the benzylic site does not change. Benzylic chlorination causes racemization.

Comment: @user55119 It's a common mistake among students that they check chirality at the reacting carbon only.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I feel...

1. When we chlorinate the two extreme -CH3, a change in the compound occurs only in those positions. So, although a chiral carbon does exist in the compound, it would not contribute to providing an isomer.
2. When we chlorinate the -CH2 and -CH, 2 isomers each would be possible as the -Cl atom can get attached in 2 ways.
   Note that this is because it would follow SN2 mechanism.
3. Phenyl group wouldn't get chlorinated cause of greater stability.
   Therefore, in total, 6 products would be formed.

Let me know if you need further clarity on any of the points.